# Spring Data JPA - entity name invalid identifier

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am implementing a simple CRUD controller but I have got some issues with JPA/Hibernate and Spring Data JPA framework. Repositories seem to work fine unless I use an entity mapped to a table with a name that contains an underscore.

**ProfileItem.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PROFILE_ITEM")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "SequenceGenerator", sequenceName = "SEQ_PROFILE_ITEM", initialValue = 1, allocationSize = 1)
public class ProfileItem implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = ApplicationConst.DEFAULT_SERIAL_VERSION_UID;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "SequenceGenerator")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "USER_ID")
    private String uid;

    private String context;

    private String application;

    @Column(name = "CREATED_ON")
    @Temporal(value = TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date createdOn;

    @Column(name = "MODIFIED_ON")
    @Temporal(value = TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date modifiedOn;

    private Long version;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "profile", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<ProfileItemData> profileItemData;

    // getters and setters ...
}
```

**ProfileItemDao.java**

```
public interface ProfileItemDao extends Repository<ProfileItem, Long> {

    public ProfileItem findById(Long id);

}
```

When I try to invoke the interface method I get the following exception:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00904: "PROFILEITE0_"."USER_ID": invalid identifier
```

Using

```
@Query("SELECT p FROM ProfileItem p WHERE p.id = :id")
public ProfileItem findById(@Param("id") Long id);
```

did not help either.

I have recreated the scenario for a table with a single word name and everything worked alright. It seems like Spring is trying to force some naming strategy.

Is there any way abandon it? Every solution I have found was tied to Spring Boot which I do not use.

Thank you in advance. I can provide some additional info if necessary.

Comment: You are sure that `PROFILE_ITEM` has a column `USER_ID` ?

Comment: As far as I know Spring has problems when you name a attribute with underscore but I do not know if the same error happens when you have a column name with underscore.

Comment: "PROFILEITE0_" looks like an alias given by the ORM. I agree with @Jens looks more like the column does not exist, as it is excplicitly mentioned in the error.

Comment: Extend `CrudRepository` remove your `findById` method and use `findOne`. Also is there REALLY a column named `USER_ID` make sure the casing matches!

Comment: Search for ORA-00904 in https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96525/e900.htm, will get the explanation of the error codes. Underscore can be used as per the documentation

Comment: Spring isn't doing anything (other than calling the JPA implementation). Your JPA implementation is doing all of that. So focus your attention on that and not on Spring. You have some SQL issued by your JPA provider, so look at it and post it perhaps? as well as the structure of your table

Comment: Thanks for the comments. @Jens and others, the column does really exist. I would post a picture of the schema but unfortunately my company restricts any file sharing website. The issue is with the "PROFILEITE0_". I think the framework somehow derived it from the table name

Comment: @m-deinum I would extend the interface using `CrudRepository` but that is not really the point. I am going to need some more methods for my service layer. This one was just to make sure everything works

Comment: without looking at the SQL invoked you can make whatever supposition you like about the origin of "PROFILEITE0_". Inspecting the SQL invoked for that exception should be step 1 in debugging and then work backwards as to why it created that

Comment: Check the full SQL that is in error.  Copy it from the logs and try running as-is on the Oracle server to see if you can spot the error.

Comment: I have submitted the answer. You guys were right all along. I would upvote the helpful comments but unfortunately, I don't have enough reputation to do so. Thank you so much anyway

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found the answer yesterday. Seems like you guys were right all along. I have added the following line in order to see the actual hibernate SQL queries

**persistence.xml**

```
<persistence-unit name="BPM" transaction-type="${persistence-unit.transaction-type}">
    <!-- snip -->
    <properties>
        <!-- snip -->
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
        <!-- snip -->
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

and

**repositoryContext.xml** (one of the config files on classpath)

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <!-- snip -->
        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
                <!-- snip -->
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <!-- snip -->
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

When I looked into the logs I realised that hibernate used the same alias `PROFILEITE0_` for both `PROFILE_ITEM` and `PROFILE_ITEM_DATA` queries when it fetched the list of related entities. So I checked the entity and DB schema for `PROFILE_ITEM_DATA` and realised that the name of one of the columns in the DB and in the entity did not match, just like you guys said.

In the DB, the name of the column used to be `USER_ID`. Then I renamed it to `ID_PROFILE_DATA` but forgot to reflect the change in the entity.

Thank you for your time and responses. They have shown me the right way.